# Saving dates to sqlite database with Active Android

Tags: java, android, date, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I have a simple class Event that I am saving into a SQlite database wtih active android like so:

Event.java

```
@Table(name = "events", id = "_id")
public class Event extends Model {

    @Column (name = "EventLocation")
    private String mEventLocation;

    @Column (name = "EventDate")
    private String mEventDate;
}
```

AddEventActivity.java:

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       String eventLocation = mEventLocation.getText().toString();
       String eventDate = mEventDate.getText().toString();
       Event event = new Event(eventLocation,eventDate);
       event.save();
```

etc. At the moment, I am saving the date as well as Start/End times as strings. But I'm adding a new feature in my app where I would like to compare the current date/time with the dates of my ArrayList of  objects and then return the next Event that will happen later that day or whatever.

What is the most efficient way to do this? I need to be able to sort my ArrayList of events by date with a Comparable or Comparator, then compare them to the current date, so I have tried parsing the strings to a Date object and with SimpleDateFormatter, but as they are Strings this doesn't really work. How can I save the dates to SQLite with Active Android? All examples  of saving I'm finding are Strings.

I'm fairly new to Java/Android. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Sorting the List**

Make your `Event` class implement `Comparable`. And in the `compareTo()` method, make comparison using the `Date`.

**Make sure the type of dateTime is `Date`** in your `Event` class.

```
public class Event extends Model implements Comparable{

...


    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
        return getDateTime().compareTo(o.getDateTime());
    }
}
```

OR, If you dont want to change you model, create Comparator on the fly

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Event>() {
  public int compare(Event o1, Event o2) {
      if (o1.getDateTime() == null || o2.getDateTime() == null)
        return 0;
      return o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime());
  }
});
```

---

**2) Storing Date to ActiveAndroid**

ActiveAndroid supports serializing Date fields automatically. It is stored internally as a timestamp (INTEGER) in milliseconds.

```
@Column(name = "timestamp", index = true)
private Date timestamp; 

//and the date will be serialized to SQLite. You can parse strings into a Date object using SimpleDateFormat:

public void setDateFromString(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy");
    sf.setLenient(true);
    this.timestamp = sf.parse(date);
}
```

Or you can create a Util method to convert `String` to `Date` which returns `Date`:

```
public Date getDateFromString(String selectedDate) throws ParseException{
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(selectedDate);
    return date;
}
```

---

**3) Comparing the date to the List of Event Objects.**

Then finally call the function to find dates later than the specified date from the List

```
public static List<Event> findRecent(Date newerThan) {
    return new Select().from(Event.class).where("timestamp > ?", newerThan.getTimeInMillis()).execute();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!! My only edit would be to mention that in in order for the getTimeInMillis() to work, I had to do:        

Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

Also, I used SQL sort my events:

    public static Event findRecent() {
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        return new Select()
                .from(Event.class)
                .orderBy("EventDateTimeStart DESC")
                .where("EventDateTimeStart > ?", rightNow.getTimeInMillis()) 
                .executeSingle();
    }

Comment: Have you checked Date support in ActiveAndroid or just CP from https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActiveAndroid-Guide?

Comment: If you want to use JodaTime's `DateTime` class type as a column field type then you need to add a custom Type Serializer for it. See this issue for more info: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/516